# Enable row selection when multiple cells selection is enabled

Tags: javascript, angular, slickgrid, angular-slickgrid

I just figured out (not documented?) that in Angular-slickgrid when you set `enableExcelCopyBuffer` flag to true, it allows you to select multiple cells.
Nevertheless, it does not work when `enableRowSelection` flag is set to true.

While I understand why both does not work together by default, is there a way to do like on Excel where row selection is possible when clicking on the row index?

I've tried with the method `setSelectedRows` but it only works when row selection is enabled thus disabling cells selection.

I've also tried to change gridOptions dynamically when clicking on a specific column but nothing happend when I call `render` method.

Comment: That is incorrect, it is documented at [Excel Copy Buffer Plugin- Wiki](https://github.com/ghiscoding/angular-slickgrid/wiki/Excel-Copy-Buffer-Plugin), also I didn't create this plugin and I actually never used it but you can see this SlickGrid [Example](http://6pac.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example-excel-compatible-spreadsheet.html) for more demo and I suggest you look at its code. There are 2 SlickGrid Selection Models (cell selection, row selection) and the plugin only works with Cell Selection Model, it should throw an error otherwise (there's no bypass)

Answer (score 1):

As mentionned, there are two SlickGrid selection models: cell selection and row selection.

If you want to use both, what I suggest is to create a column which contains the index of the row, like in Excel. This one will be used to do row selection. If we click on a cell from this column, we switch the selection model by using `setSelectionModel` from SlickGrid. To take these changes into account, you have to call `invalidate`.

Here is a partial example where `OnClick` method is binded to `(onClick)`:

```
angularGrid: AngularGridInstance;
gridOptions: GridOption;

angularGridReady(grid: AngularGridInstance) {
    this.angularGrid = grid;
}

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.gridOptions = {
    enableCellNavigation: true,
    //enableRowSelection: true, // If set to true, it disable cells selection 
    enableExcelCopyBuffer: true // Enable copy but also cells selection
  };
}

onClick(event: Event, args: any) {
  if (args.cell != 0) { // Click NOT in index column
    if (this.angularGrid.slickGrid.getSelectionModel() instanceof SlickRowSelectionModel) {
      this.angularGrid.slickGrid.setSelectionModel(new SlickCellSelectionModel());
      this.angularGrid.slickGrid.invalidate();
    }
  } else {
    if (this.angularGrid.slickGrid.getSelectionModel() instanceof SlickCellSelectionModel) {
      this.angularGrid.slickGrid.setSelectionModel(new SlickRowSelectionModel());
      this.angularGrid.slickGrid.invalidate();
    }
  }
}
```